# User password reset link leads to access denied page

Tags: users, drush

**Command:**
drush uli

**Output:**
http://default/user/reset/uid/..../...hash.../login

The output URL normally logs you in automatically, but it gets takes to access denied error instead.

Comment: Simply run `$ drush uli -l http://example.com` next time.

Answer (score -1):

To Fix It

1. Go to /admin/config/people/accounts
2. Disable "Require email verification when a visitor creates an account"

If you are not able to login to your admin account because your one-time login link does not work. And you have access to use Drush.

1. drush cset user.settings verify_mail 0

If you don't have access to use Drush

1. Maybe other people can answer this one.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the actual question IMHO. (leymannx posted the correct answer as a comment.)